# How to do grid paging by offset?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to implement a paging grid of people, similar to Gmail contacts, where the grid loads a maximum of N people's names, the paging bar says something like 'Allen - Baxter', and you can page through the alphabetical list. The main differences with the stock ExtJS pager is:

(a) This custom pager doesn't use a page number from beginning, but rather it uses an offset to begin the query (e.g. Baxter). On the server side, it actually queries names > Baxter.

(b)The pager won't know total count of people or pages, because the server doesn't check this. It just queries users > Baxter up to N people.

I guess you can sort of call it "infinite paging".

Is there a simpler approach to this problem other than writing a totally custom pager class (and possibly making changes to grid, store, and/or proxy classes)?

Comment: Do you have control over the server? Or is it a hard requirement to "not know" total count, and page sizes?

Comment: I do have control, and the correct way to do 'paging' on my NoSQL database is to query by starting value, not by page number offset. And it does not automatically know total count. Say there are 3000 values that match a query. The DB will not follow an index for 3000 keys to determine total count. It will start where I tell it to, and read 25 keys. I have no idea how many follow it.

Comment: Another thought: The whole premise of Ext JS paging is for small sets of data that you can prefetch and count. When the query set gets to a certain size, the design falls apart. In contract, look at Gmail: for small search queries, it tells you total matches, and you can page through them just like Ext JS. But for large match sets, it just tells you that there are "Many" matches, and then you page through them, probably via a query that checks for messages after last match. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, I think the approach I would take, if you don't want it to be a long project is to "cheat" and give a very large number as the total count, and just change the display on the toolbar.. It should work as long as you can fetch a constant number of rows for each page

Comment: It's more than a total count issue. It's also about determining where the query begins. When you page in Ext JS (even the "infinite" grid which is baloney), it uses a "start" parameter which is a numeric offset from the beginning of the query. That means each time you load a new page, the server needs to re-perform the entire query from the beginning and count N items to get to your next page. A smart query would be, for example, for 50,000 people, to begin a query beginning after the name of the last person's name. Ext JS is missing this enterprise feature.

Comment: But you can send the last name with each fetch, and count X rows from there, no?

Comment: That's one thing to do, but there's more, because the whole premise of the ext js toolbar is based on page counts (i.e., when to enable page buttons, what to do when clicking each page button). I have to design an entirely different set of client-server parameters (e..g, client tells server: start at beginning, after X value, before X value, go to end. server tells client whether there are more rows.)

Comment: Yeah, well.. sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Thank you for engaging in conversation. I'm just surprised that I don't see anyone else ask/discuss this issue anywhere. It seems to me essential, but maybe I just think strange. I'd rather page with a real range than page counts (i.e., name alphabetically, date-times in order, etc.), and it's a much more efficient database query.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a working solution by creating my own toolbar class which is basically a copy-paste of Ext.toolbar.Paging that changes almost every method. The two client parameters I used to specify the type of request is: (1) direction, and (2) cursor. Those two parameters together can identify every type of paging request: (a) first, (b) next, (c) previous, (d) last. Other than the limit parameter, the class ignores the existing paging behavior built into ExtJs; it's an entirely different paradigm. And the server also includes a response parameter called hasMore, tells the client whether there are more items in the direction it is paging. So the server then always queries one more item than the limit to determine whether there is more.